# Rails Assign a value to child table from parent table on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to create "visits", which belong to "branches". I'm able to assign the branch_id to each visit, but how can I assign other fields from "branches" to "visits"? For example, I would like to add the branch_name field to the visits table without the user having to select this value in the form. Would I be able to use something like "before_save"? Can I have the collection_select field save the branch_name as well as the branch_id?

branches_controller.rb:

```
class BranchesController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @branches = Branch.new
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @branch }
    end
  end

  def create
    @branches = Branch.new(branch_params)
    @branches.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @branches.save
        redirect_to main_app.user_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  def show
    @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
    @visits = Visit.where(branch_id: @branch.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show_visits
    @branch = Branch.find(params[:branch_params])
    @visits = Visit.where(branch_id: @branch.id)
  end

  private

  def set_branch
    @branch = Branch.find(params[:id])
  end

  def branch_params
    params.require(:branch).permit(:branch_name, :photo, :first_name, :last_name, :telephone_number, :contact_email, :address_line_1, :address_line_2, :city, :postcode)
  end

end
```

visits_controller.rb:

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [ :new]
  before_action :set_visit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @visits = Visit.all
    @visits_by_date = @visits.group_by(&:date_from)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @visit = Visit.new
    @branch = Branch.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @visit = current_user.visits.new(visit_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @visit.save
        format.html { redirect_to @visit, notice: 'Visit was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @visit }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @visit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @visit.update(visit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @visit, notice: 'Visit was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @visit }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @visit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @visit.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to visits_url, notice: 'Visit was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_visit
      @visit = Visit.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def visit_params
      params.require(:visit).permit(:location, :date_from, :time_from, :date_to, :time_to, :comment, :branch_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

branch.rb:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :visits

  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  before_save :capitalize_attributes

  def capitalize_attributes
         capitalizable = ["first_name","last_name", "city", "branch_name"]
     self.attributes.each do |attr,val|
       #based on comment either of these will work
       #if you want to store nil in the DB then
       self.send("#{attr}=",val.strip.capitalize) if capitalizable.include?(attr) && !val.nil?
       #if you want to store a blank string in the DB then 
       self.send("#{attr}=",val.to_s.strip.capitalize) if capitalizable.include?(attr)
     end
   end

 def branch_name_select
   "#{branch_name}, #{address_line_1}, #{address_line_2}, #{city}, #{postcode}"
 end

end
```

visit.rb:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :branch  
    belongs_to :user #:as => 'created_by' 
    validates_uniqueness_of :time_from, :scope => [:date_from, :location], :message=>"slot is already taken on selected date"

end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.user_type == 'client' %>


<%= form_for @visit do |f| %>
  <% if @visit.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@visit.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this visit from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @visit.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :branch_id, "Please Pick Service Provider/Branch you would like to visit:" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :branch_name_select, {prompt: "Select the Branch/Service"}, {:required => true}) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date_from, "Please Pick Visit Date From:" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :date_from, :required => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time_from, "Please Pick Visit Start Time:" %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :time_from, {:start_hour => 9, :end_hour => 20, :minute_step => 15,  :ampm => true}, :required => true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date_to, "Please Pick Visit Date To:" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :date_to %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time_to, "Please Pick Visit End Time:" %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :time_to, {:start_hour => 9, :end_hour => 20, :minute_step => 15, :ampm => true} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment, "If you have any specific requirements for your visit please let us now and leave the comment below:" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit Visit Request"%>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: you can use the callback `after_create` if you want to save the branch attributes in visitor on `creation` of visitor. but why you need to save same attributes when you can easily access them through branch. can visitor update them on there own.? if not, then it is not good practise to duplicate data in table.

Comment: It's best to just access the branch name using `@visit.branch.name`. Adding the branch's name to the visit table is unnecessary. Duplication is hardly ever the right answer

Comment: Thanks very much guys, completely forgot that @visit.branch.name was a thing that you can do.